# Call Controller ActionResult to modify ViewBag variable and reload View?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I have an MVC5 application. My **HomeController** on application load fills a simple list that gets passed to the **Index** View via the *ViewBag* and passes my Model to the View. On the View I also have a grid component with the paging size set by the *ViewBag* variable (on load, the default is 10 records):

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> pagingIntervalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "250", Value = "250" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "500", Value = "500" });
        ViewBag.pagingIntervalList = pagingIntervalList;

        // Set default paging to 10 records on Load.
        ViewBag.PageSize = 10;

        var assetList = db.INV_ASSETS.ToList();
        return View(assetList);
    }
```

On this View, I'm attempting to use the `@Html.DropDownList()` that I fill using the `SelectList` from the Controller and allow users to specify the interval they wish paging to occur at (5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, etc.):

```
<span class="gridPagerInterval label label-primary">Page every @Html.DropDownList("pagingIntervalList") Records. </span>
```

What I cannot figure out is how to reload the View with the newly selected `paging interval`. In my attempts I have created copy of my `Index()` controller action that expects a parameter value which should be used in the ViewBag and passed to the View to set the new selection for paging records:

```
public ActionResult NewPagingInterval(string selection)
        {
            List<SelectListItem> pagingIntervalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "250", Value = "250" });
            pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "500", Value = "500" });
            ViewBag.pagingIntervalList = pagingIntervalList;

            // Set paging to user selected value.
            ViewBag.PageSize = selection;

            var assetList = db.INV_ASSETS.ToList();
            return View(assetList);
        }
```

I attempted to achieve my desired functionality using a `JSON` call below, but I need the View to be reloaded and make use of the newly specified `ViewBag.PageSize` value, not just simply reload as is:

```
       $("#pagingIntervalList").on("change", function (e) {
            var data = { selection: $("#pagingIntervalList").val() };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: '@Url.Action("NewPagingInterval", "HOME")',
                data: data,
                success: function (resp) {
                    //alert("Success! Asset " + resp.ID + " successfully verified on " + resp.VDate);
                    location.reload(true);
                },
                error: function (resp) {
                    alert("There was an error with modifying the Paging interval...");
                }
            });
        });
```

I then thought maybe I could call my `NewPagingInterval(string selection)` Controller Action by passing the Parameter via URL which eventually I put together the below:

```
$("#pagingIntervalList").on("change", function (e) {
    window.location = "/Home/NewPagingInterval?selection=" + $("#pagingIntervalList").val();
});
```

This successfully calls my `NewPagingInterval(string selection)` Action on the Controller, but after the `return View(assetList)` gives me:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

The view 'NewPagingInterval' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/NewPagingInterval.aspx
~/Views/Home/NewPagingInterval.ascx
~/Views/Shared/NewPagingInterval.aspx
~/Views/Shared/NewPagingInterval.ascx
~/Views/Home/NewPagingInterval.cshtml
~/Views/Home/NewPagingInterval.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/NewPagingInterval.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/NewPagingInterval.vbhtml
~/__MVCSITEMAPPROVIDER/NewPagingInterval.ascx
```

Can someone more experienced see where I'm going wrong or have a better idea to achieve what I am after?

---

Attempting haim's Git example:

```
    // Initial Controller Action -- Loads Fine
    public ActionResult Index(int pageSize = 10)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> pagingIntervalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "250", Value = "250" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "500", Value = "500" });
        ViewBag.pagingIntervalList = pagingIntervalList;

        // Set default paging to 10 records on Load.
        ViewBag.PageSize = pageSize;

        var assetList = db.INV_ASSETS.ToList();
        return View(assetList);
    }

// Form & DropDown
<form id="pagingIntervalForm" method="post" action="@Url.Action("NewPagingInterval", "HOME")">
    <span class="gridPagerInterval label label-primary">Page every @Html.DropDownList("pagingIntervalList") Records. </span>
</form> 

// Submit Form -- successfully calls NewPagingInterval Controller Action

// value of "selection" parameter is NULL!
$("#pagingIntervalList").on("change", function (e) {
      $('#pagingIntervalForm').submit();
});


    // Successfully called, but returns nothing but the raw data in text format of my Model.ToList().....?
    public ActionResult NewPagingInterval(string selection)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> pagingIntervalList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value = "5" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value = "10" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value = "25" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "50", Value = "50" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "100", Value = "100" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "250", Value = "250" });
        pagingIntervalList.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "500", Value = "500" });
        ViewBag.pagingIntervalList = pagingIntervalList;

        // Set paging to user selected value.
        ViewBag.PageSize = selection;

        var assetList = db.INV_ASSETS.ToList();
        return Json(assetList);
    }
```

Comment: Your `$.ajax` code implies that you're expecting the server to return `JSON`. By calling `return View()` in the server, you're not return `JSON` but a `text/html` response. Also, since you didn't really create that View file, you're getting the exception that says the View file is missing.

Comment: Try `return Json(assetList);` instead.

Comment: Ok, I changed `return View(assetList)` to `return Json(assetList)`. This reloads my View, but I'm still only showing the default `10` records for paging instead of the `50` I had changed the dropdown to. On successful return, my `ajax()` call is specifying `location.reload(true)` which if I'm understanding correctly is simply doing a refresh of the page, not actually populating the View anew with the newly set `ViewBag` variables. This behavior is why I had moved to trying to pass the parameter via `window.location`...?

Comment: What's the point of returning `JSON` from the server if you don't do anything about it and immediately refresh the page? If you do need a view to be returned (with the correct page-size selected) then avoid Ajax and simply `POST` to the original `Index()` action.

Comment: Can you provide an example haim? I had originally wanted to just call the `Index()` action again, but I need a way to specify what the user has selected via the dropdown and use that new value to set the `ViewBag` variable -- recalling the `Index()` as is will always result in a `10` page pagination setting.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18d272c806dca3f09ad4 Or simply use `GET` as proposed by @MJ Vakili's answer.

Comment: @haim770, Please see my Edit above. I tried your example and something seems to be off about the call to `NewPagingInterval`. Instead of the View fully returned I'm simply getting the Raw text values of my `Model.ToList()` and the `selection` parameter in the action is coming across as `null` when called.

Comment: you not need NewPagingInterval action and not need return json . please test my code is right.

Comment: I made a mistake in the Url. Try `action="@Url.Action("Index", "HOME")"`.

Comment: @haim770, Ok, I changed to `action="@Url.Action("Index", "HOME")"` but since the parameter is directly set at `10` -- `public ActionResult Index(int pageSize = 10)` there is no value being passed in. Each call via this example just returns the same View over and over specified to page at 10 records each time.

Comment: My mistake, change the parameter name to `pagingIntervalList`.

Comment: I'm not following? `pagingIntervalList` is the name of my `List<SelectListItem>` in the Controller.

Comment: @haim770, Can you post an example here of what you mean? `pagingIntervalList` is the same name used for my `List<SelectListItem>` so I cannot use that as a parameter name.

Comment: You need the name of the `<select>` element to match the parameter name. It could also be `@Html.DropDownList("foo")` and have it matched to `public ActionResult Index(int foo = 10)`.

Comment: How does that work though? The way I have it declared as `@Html.DropDownList("pagingIntervalList")` is to make it bind to to `ViewBag.pagingIntervalList` from my Controller. I'm not understanding how I can have the parameter ALSO declared as `pagingIntervalList` to bind with the form submission?

Comment: @haim770? Did you see my last comment?

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic, That was my mistake. My last gist would not even compile. You just have to have the name of the dropdown match the name of the parameter, then you could store it in `ViewBag.PageSize`.

Comment: @haim770 could you post what you are meaning here or update your github link above? I'm still not entirely following -- mostly because (on load) the user will not have yet made a selection, so there MUST be a declaration of page size first -- then I need to reference user selection to change paging.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your NewPagingInterval action:

ViewBag.pagingIntervalList = new SelectList(pagingIntervalList, "Value", "Text", selection);